# How can I get an updated cookie in header.php?

Tags: cookies

I have trouble with getting an updated cookie.

For example, I create a cookie like this in functions.php:

```
function set_menu_id_cookie()
{
    setcookie('menu_id', 1000, 2147483647, "/");
}

add_action('init', 'set_menu_id_cookie');
```

then I have `$_COOKIE['menu_id']` in header.php and I refresh the page and I get 'null'.

then I refresh the page one more time and then I get 1000.

it's the same when I update cookie. For example, I set the 'menu_id' cookie to '1001', refresh page, but I get old value- '1000'. I refresh one more time and only then I get new value- '1001'.

how can I set a cookie and receive it updated right away?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352349/why-the-cookie-value-is-not-updated-at-once-when-i-submit-the-form

Comment: @JacobPeattie so, the best way would be 
setcookie('menu_id', 1001, 2147483647, '/');
$_COOKIE['menu_id'] = 1001;
?